What are the adverbs doing here?
on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverb-phrases there are examples of adverbs of place and averb phrases....
"I’m upstairs"
"They’re right there" — am I correct in saying these two examples the pronouns "I'm" and "they're" are being modified by the adverb/adverb phrase? If so, I don't recall reading in any of my books or on any website where it mentions that an adverb modifies (describes) a pronoun — its usually mentioned that an adverb modifies (describes) a verb, adjective or another adverb.
Can anyone please clarify this? thanks

"They're" is not a pronoun.  It is short for "They are".  "They" is a pronoun, and "are" is a verb.
Similarly, "I'm" is not a pronoun.  It is short for "I am".  "I" is a pronoun, and "am" is a verb.
Specifically, "are" and "am" are copulas, which link a subject to an attribute of the subject.  In these examples, the attribute is a location.
"Right" is modifying "there", not "They".

OP's query:


"I’m upstairs."
"They’re right there."
its usually mentioned that an adverb modifies (describes) a verb, adjective or another adverb.



In sentence 1, the adverb "upstairs" and in sentence 2, the phrase "right there" modify the entire sentence by adding a sense of place. Here, "right" acts as an intensifier for  "there."

An adverb is a word that modifies a verb (e.g., “he sings loudly”), an adjective (e.g., “very tall”), "another adverb* (e.g., “ended too quickly”), or even an entire sentence. "Upstairs" and "right there" are examples of adverbs of location, which tell us where something happens or exists.
Common adverbs of location include:

abroad,
overseas,
here,
there,
indoors,
outdoors,
upstairs,
downstairs,
away,
round home,
nearby,
around,
next door.


on 2nd glance — the webpage says the underlined "I'm" and "theyre" words are being modified, hence why I did not think it was a sentence being modified rather it was the words.
